# Fix and Unfix scroll menu past the height of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that gets fixed when you scroll to a certain position. However I need it to return to it's regular position and become unfixed when it scrolls past the content it is supporting.

So I need to calculate the height of the content container div and once it get to the end, unfix the menu.

This is because if I keep scrolling to the bottom of the page my menu keeps staying fixed even when iv'e scrolled onto my footer.

So how can I change this so that the scroll is only fixed to the height of the div that the fixed menu is supporting `#js-contracts`.

```
            $(function(){
                function fixDiv() {
                    var $cache = $('#js-contracts');
                    var divHeight = $('#js-months').height();
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1210 & $(window).scrollTop() < divHeight+1210)
                    $cache.css({
                        'position': 'fixed',
                        'top': '63px',
                        'width':'inherit',
                        'padding-top':'10px',
                        'padding-bottom':'10px',
                        'background-color':'white'
                    });
                    else
                    $cache.css({
                        'position': 'relative',
                        'top': 'auto',
                        'background-color':'none',
                        'padding-bottom':'10px',
                    });
                }
                $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
                fixDiv();
            });
```

Comment: Doesn't `position:sticky` do the trick ?

Comment: I can get it to stick and be fixed, but it fixes past the point of the content when scrolling past it, So I have to unstick it when it is less than 2970 which is going to vary on different screen widths